# Apex queries performed on Sandbox but not in production

Tags: apex

I am doing quite simple apex queries that are perfectly working on Sandbox

```
List<Country__c> RelevantCountryList = [select id, name, Region__r.Name, CreatedDate from Country__c 
                                                where Id in (select country_link__c from Market__c where Focus_Year__c = True)];
        List<Market__c> RelevantMarketData = [select Id, country_link__c, focus_year__c,status__c, Name, CreatedDate from Market__c where country_link__r.Id IN :RelevantCountryList and Focus_Year__c = True ] ;
        
        List<Market__History> MarketHistory = [SELECT id, ParentId, OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedById, CreatedDate FROM Market__History where ParentId IN :RelevantMarketData];
        List<Lead>RelevantPropertyData = [select Id, Name, Market__r.country_link__r.Id, LeadSource, Status, CreatedDate  from Lead where Market__r.Id IN :RelevantMarketData];
        List<LeadHistory> PropHistory = [Select Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate, DataType, LeadId, Field, IsDeleted, NewValue, OldValue From LeadHistory where LeadId IN :RelevantPropertyData];
        List<Opportunity> RelevantOpportunityData = [Select Id, StageName, main_related_property__r.Market__r.country_link__r.Id, CreatedDate from Opportunity Where main_related_property__r.Id IN :RelevantPropertyData];
        List<OpportunityHistory> OppHistory = [Select Amount, CloseDate, CreatedById, CreatedDate, ExpectedRevenue, ForecastCategory,  Id, OpportunityId,  PrevAmount, PrevCloseDate, Probability, StageName From OpportunityHistory where OpportunityId IN :RelevantOpportunityData];
        //Creating the List to push
        Map<String, List<wrapperClass>> MaptoPush = new Map<String, List<wrapperClass>>();
        List<wrapperClass> wrapperList = new List<wrapperClass>();
        List<wrapperClass> wrapperList2 = new List<wrapperClass>();
        List<wrapperClass> wrapperList3 = new List<wrapperClass>();
        system.debug('RelevantMarketData ' + RelevantMarketData);
        system.debug('RelevantPropertyData ' + RelevantPropertyData);
        system.debug('RelevantOpportunityData ' + RelevantOpportunityData);
```

now that I moved my code to production, and I system debug .. everything is empty ..
any idea ?
am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Either there is permission issue or please make sure you have records in the objects that you have queried.
Thanks

Comment: Does the running user have record-level access to the records you are attempting to query?